# Trouble using loadHTMLString in Swift

Tags: swift, webview, base-url

I'm trying to make an app that will scrape data off of a site then load it. I've managed to scrape it with:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myURL) {(data, response, error) in
```

de-encode it with:

```
let newStr = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
```

and I'm trying to load it with:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(newStr, baseURL:"")
```

But if I leave it blank it just crashes and gives this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I'm not sure what to set the baseURL as because I'm creating the string in app.

What should I set the baseURL to?

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't coming from the `data!` unwrapping expression?

Comment: I've used it with and without the ! if thats what you mean. but no, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: but I've tried the two answers and they didn't work so maybe I was mistaken about the problem.

Comment: Add `print`s around each statement just to be extra sure where the error is coming from (or better yet: use the debugger bro, if you are comfortable with Xcode).

Comment: I have a print() function for newStr and it does have the right data.

Comment: BTW, is that `webView` of yours correctly defined? If this is an `@IBOutlet`, have you linked it from your storyboard?

Comment: yes, and just to be sure I did it again and ran it again with the same results.

Comment: Look very carefully in your debug area/console, your error might be coming from somewhere else...

Comment: A small note that probably isn't important: I set the

Comment: 'webView.loadHTMLString(newStr, baseURL:"")'

Comment: to self.webView.loadHTMLString(newStr, baseURL:"")

Comment: the only other thing in it is "(lldb)"

Comment: Looks ok to me, but use `baseURL:nil` just to be sure.

Comment: what do you mean "pass"?

Comment: Samething as both answers below, sorry ;-)

Comment: so like this:                  '            self.webView.loadHTMLString(newStr, baseURL: nil)'

Comment: It still gives the same error.

Comment: I agree with Paolo.  You seem to have two problems and we solved one of them.  We need to know which optional is being complained about. Can you use "if let" syntax to ensure that you never have an optional?

Comment: sure, one minute.

Comment: @Mozahler If I do it with the "let myURL" part it gives this error:                  Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'URL'.

Comment: Good. That means it is not the problem. Your error involves an optional. If is the line you say, that only leaves the webView. Try to prove that your webView is not nil.

Comment: @PauloMattos if I do it with the "let task" part it gives this error: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: and if I put in the ; then it gives the error: "Expected expression"

Comment: @Mozahler sorry didn't get your comment till I did a few more

Comment: @Mozahler Il try it

Comment: @Mozahler how do I prove my webView isn't nil?

Comment: In Xcode, add a breakpoint at that line. execute the code/run the app. when it stops at the line, verify that you have a valid web view being pointed to by the variable, not just a bunch of zeros (or nil)

Comment: @Mozahler what kind of breakpoint do I add?

Comment: @Mozahler nvm it say webView = (UIwebView!) nil.

Comment: so it looks like you were right

Comment: @PauloMattos now I don't suppose either of you know how to fix said problem?

Comment: Yes, I just made an edit to my answer with explicit instructions in my answer. If you get stuck, let me know and I'll give more explicit instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the empty string `""`, just use `nil` as the `baseURL`.

Edit:

Now that you've determined that your webView is nil, the rest should be easy! Go to your code where you initialize the webView, add error messages as appropriate to see why it isn't succeeding. (a nil webView means either it failed initialization, or you never initialized it...)

Comment: You should go through the code and make sure your optionals are actually populated using standard syntax "if let webView = ... { }". We need to know what is nil before we can help further.

Comment: Thanks, Paulo, I appreciate it. You have a very impressive profile!